# Using regular expressions to calculate Unique users?

Tags: c#, regex

I want to define a Regular expression pattern that will give unique user counts in a file. One more thing i also want to apply length count such that Users value does not exceed more than 15 characters.
 So that my code will return 2 in the logs provided below as it should discard users value exceeding length 15.
 Logs file format :

```
 User:fd441f1f-22c0-45d2-b020-32e1e6a15a73 
 User:fd441f1f-22c0-45d2-b020-32e1e6a15f43
 User:fd441f1f-24g0-45d2-b050-32e1e6a15a73
 User: karansha
 User: gulanand
```

Code i tried:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"User:\s*(?<username>.*?)\s");
            MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(x);
            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {
                var user = match.Groups["username"].Value;
                if (!users.Contains(user)) users.Add(user);
            }
            int numberOfUsers = users.Count;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use a `Regex` for this.
Try using `string.Split()` and `Distinct` instead.

```
int numberOfUsers = x.Split(new string[] { "User:" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                     .Distinct()
                     .Count(name => name.Length < 15);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with LINQ:

```
int numberOfUsers = regex.Matches(x)
                         .Cast<Match>()
                         .Select(m => m.Groups["username"].Value)
                         .Distinct() // pick only unique names
                         .Count(name => name.Length < 15); // calculate count
```

Or without regular expressions:

```
int numberOfUsers = File("log.txt")
                      .ReadLines()
                      .Select(line => line.Replace("User:", "").Trim())
                      .Distinct()
                      .Count(name => name.Length < 15);
```

Comment: what about length count ? You see in my logs i donot want my program to calculate user values exceeding length 15. Can you help me with Regex ?

Comment: @KamalRai simply add condition in Count method. It will calculate only users which match that condition.